# Android Studio: open drawer button id

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

For an Android app, I want to implement the tourguide library (https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide) for the button that is encircled in red.

But I had that code autogenerated by Android Studio and I need the id of that button in order to call findViewById(R.id.....)

Does anyone know how to retrieve or set the id?

[image: Open Drawer Button]

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout).getTouchables().get(0);